# Can I travel to Denmark with EU blue card?

Tags: blue-card, denmark

I have an EU blue card, is it possible to go to Denmark with this EU blue card?

Comment: For how long and for what purpose? What's your place of residence (the country that issued your EU Blue card)?

Comment: Just to visit Denmark. Germany has issued me the blue card two years ago.

Answer (score 3):

A German EU Blue Card is also a residence permit from a Schengen country (namely Germany) and as such exempts you from any potential Schengen short-stay visa requirement. You can therefore use it to enter Denmark for a short visit either directly from Germany or from anywhere else inside or outside the Schengen area.

Beyond that, Denmark does *not* participate in the EU Blue Card system, which means that you cannot use the special Blue Card rules to move or work there. In that case, you would have to apply for the relevant Danish long-stay visa from your current place of residence *before* entering Denmark. This is why you may have heard that the EU Blue Card doesn't apply in Denmark (which is true in the sense I just explained but doesn't mean that visits are not permitted).

Comment: Thank you once again

Comment: Your passport **together** with the residence permit card is required. The residence permit card itself is **not** a travel document.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Excellent point. Note that in some countries, it is actually possible and legal to use the residence card as an ID for many purpose (albeit typically only a local one). A travel document is definitely needed to returrn to Germany or at the Schengen external border, though.